# What is the definition of "each test" when Cypress docs say "between each test"?

Tags: cypress

The Cypress docs *Best Practices* section, under the heading ["Is resetting the state necessary?"](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Is-resetting-the-state-necessary) says the following:

> Remember, Cypress already automatically clears localStorage, cookies, sessions, etc before each test.

**Does "each test" mean "each `it()` block"?**

Given the following code, and it's comments, is the second `it()` block technically cookie-less, and session-less, and passing just because we're lucky that the page hasn't changed?

```js
describe('When logged in', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.customLoginAndSetSomeCookies()
    cy.visit('/page-for-logged-in-folks-only')
  })

  it('I can see some stuff!', () => {
    // `before` ran and set up cookies for us.
    // `visit` set the page for us.
    // So this passes just fine.
    cy.get('#welcome').should('contain', 'You can see me!')
  })

  it('Is this a new test? Am I logged out?', () => {
    // Am I technically cookie-less here, but since 
    // I'm still on this page I can still see this?
    // (Passes, but only because no page transition?)
    cy.get('#welcome').should('contain', 'You can see me!')
  })
})
```

If I'm correct, then while these may pass fine, the problem comes if we try to do some "logged in" stuff in the second `it()` block. So the better pattern would probably be to combine these into a larger single block, or use `beforeEach` instead of `before`... BUT, I'm not confident in that answer, **because I'm not sure the definition of "each test".**

Comment: Given that `it` (or, er, `test`) defines a test, why would it mean anything else?

Comment: It's called `it`, and my introduction to these kinds of tests has been using Cypress (and therefore Mocha). Why would it mean anything else? Well, because software and ecosystems are large, and a given persons' entry point may not be from fundamentals. Your comment could have been a simple answer pointing to the Mocha or Cypress docs that mention that one is an alias of another. So yes, why would it? Why would it not? If one doesn't know the answer to the question, perhaps that's why they would post here?  Welcome back to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I found your answer, from their [pricing page](https://cypress.io/pricing) :)

> What counts as a test recording?
> We consider each time the it() function is called to be a single test. Only test runs configured to record to the Dashboard Service when running Cypress headlessly count toward your plan limit.